# strace not showing anything for thread at 100% 'system' CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, linux-kernel, strace

I'm having difficulty with my Python app going to 100% 'system' CPU time across multiple threads for up to 10+ seconds. My (limited) understanding is that 'system' CPU time is time spent in the kernel. `strace` shows what kernel calls are being made and (optionally) how long they take. I've managed to run strace on one thread during one of these pauses but the strace output just has a gap for that period and the calls either side of that gap are shown with a very short time.

How do I run strace properly to figure out what kernel call is happening?

In my Python app I use a separate thread and `psutil` to check for any threads with high system CPU and then log them out. Once I see one I use the following command line to start strace:

```
strace -tT -o ~/strace.log -p <PID of thread>
```

Logging from my app (uses `psutil` under the hood):

```
2015-05-19 08:05:47,025 WARNING:log.cpu Logging paused for 0.34s to 08:05:46.985768 - longer than expected - other threads probably delayed as well
2015-05-19 08:05:47,026 WARNING:log.cpu This process utilization (CPUs) user: 0.1, system: 52.4 | OS (%) scputimes(user=0.4, nice=0.0, system=80.2, idle=19.3, iowait=0.0, irq=0.0, softirq=0.0, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0), memory used: 16.6, threads: 101, fds: 70
2015-05-19 08:05:47,027 WARNING:log.cpu Thread 47441 utilization (CPUs) user: 0.0, system: 1.0
2015-05-19 08:05:47,512 WARNING:log.cpu This process utilization (CPUs) user: 0.1, system: 61.4 | OS (%) scputimes(user=0.5, nice=0.0, system=99.4, idle=0.1, iowait=0.0, irq=0.0, softirq=0.0, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0), memory used: 16.6, threads: 101, fds: 70
2015-05-19 08:05:47,516 WARNING:log.cpu Thread 47441 utilization (CPUs) user: 0.0, system: 0.9
2015-05-19 08:05:47,995 WARNING:log.cpu This process utilization (CPUs) user: 0.3, system: 63.7 | OS (%) scputimes(user=0.8, nice=0.0, system=99.2, idle=0.0, iowait=0.0, irq=0.0, softirq=0.0, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0), memory used: 16.6, threads: 101, fds: 70
2015-05-19 08:05:47,995 WARNING:log.cpu Thread 47441 utilization (CPUs) user: 0.0, system: 0.8
2015-05-19 08:05:48,495 WARNING:log.cpu This process utilization (CPUs) user: 0.3, system: 63.8 | OS (%) scputimes(user=0.7, nice=0.0, system=99.3, idle=0.0, iowait=0.0, irq=0.0, softirq=0.0, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0), memory used: 16.6, threads: 101, fds: 70
2015-05-19 08:05:48,496 WARNING:log.cpu Thread 47441 utilization (CPUs) user: 0.0, system: 0.8
2015-05-19 08:05:52,140 WARNING:log.cpu Logging paused for 3.12s to 08:05:52.103363 - longer than expected - other threads probably delayed as well
2015-05-19 08:05:52,153 WARNING:log.cpu This process utilization (CPUs) user: 0.0, system: 63.6 | OS (%) scputimes(user=0.3, nice=0.0, system=98.5, idle=1.2, iowait=0.0, irq=0.0, softirq=0.0, steal=0.0, guest=0.0, guest_nice=0.0), memory used: 16.6, threads: 101, fds: 70
2015-05-19 08:05:52,180 WARNING:log.cpu Thread 47441 utilization (CPUs) user: 0.0, system: 1.0
```

strace log during the same period on that thread ID 47441:

```
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b305ac, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000030>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000016>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000017>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000021>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000053>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000023>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000020>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000019>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000021>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.000574>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b30f2c, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000019>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b3072c, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000028>
08:05:46 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000022>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.000305>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b31fac, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000119>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b319ac, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000073>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.000474>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b31f2c, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000094>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b30dac, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000096>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.001139>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b31eac, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000156>
08:05:46 futex(0x7f7b46b303ac, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000059>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000081>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000050>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.001603>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b31d2c, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000318>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b30f2c, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000259>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000048>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000060>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000203>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.000148>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000036>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000164>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.003125>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000053>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000052>
08:05:52 sched_yield()                  = 0 <0.000023>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b3202c, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) = 0 <0.002264>
08:05:52 futex(0x7f7b46b3122c, FUTEX_WAKE, 1) = 1 <0.000119>
```

Note how strace is logging 100's of entries per second and then there's a 6 second gap of nothing. But no calls are shown as taking more than a couple milliseconds. So how come that thread showed 100% 'system' CPU time?

I've used `top` to confirm that `psutil` is reporting correct numbers. And I'm sure I've traced the correct thread because the 6 second gap corresponds exactly to the high CPU time recorded by psutil.

Help also appreciated with what other tools could I use to figure what is causing this kernel/system time?

Environment:
- Python 3.4.3 (issue seen on Python 2.7 as well)
- CentOS 7 kernel 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 (problem seen on Ubuntu 12 LTS as well)
- 64 core AMD machine

Comment: Have you tried tracing your python app to see what line of code does it hang on? Something like `python -m trace -t app.py`? (it slows down the python app a lot, but may provide insight)

Comment: @Fox I have so many threads that strace run across all of them makes the app run so slowly that it doesn't work and doesn't show the problem. That's why I had to resort to only strace on one thread. I've been presuming python tracing would be even slower. Been doing some more research and I might try ltrace.

Comment: Actually i'd go with tracing it all and saving output to files (usually works) `strace -ff -o file` ... it will create many files, but who knows what we might find  ...

Comment: Tracing to files is **much** faster than tracing to a terminal. Much of it has to rendering of fonts I think. (eg. xterm is much faster than gnome-terminal)

Comment: I'm doing all of this through SSH as the machine is halfway around the world. I tried `strace -f -b execve -o ...` originally but the main process CPU usage dropped from 3000% (i.e. full CPU across 30+ cores as it uses the very parallelised OpenCV) down to about 50% and the problem no longer appeared.

Comment: strace only shows syscalls. For library calls use ltrace. For inefficient code, use profiling (that one is language specific).

Comment: @Dan I will try `ltrace` today but I would have thought since the CPU time is all 'system' and not 'user' that it is time spent in a syscall? Or is that not correct?

Comment: Tried `ltrace` but unlike `strace` it's `-p` parameter doesn't accept thread IDs. `ltrace` even without `-f` makes the app so slow that it doesn't run properly and doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: Try strace -c <rest of arguments>, that will report a summary of syscalls

Comment: I finally got the info I needed using `gdb`. Wrote a Python app that watched my app and sent SIGHUP when system CPU was high so `gdb` broke in allowing me to inspect it. But that isn't the answer to my question: I still don't understand why when `top` and other tools show 100% 'system' CPU usage that `strace` is not showing any calls using that time.

Comment: have you tried `perf`?